# I need an example of how to send AT COMMANDS to SIm7000E GPS+LTE module from ESP32 and reading those response in Serial monitor

Tags: serial, esp32, hardware, uart

Actually I need to make HTTPS post request using SIM7000 and ESP32 but the available libraries don't have a function for HTTPS post request, I wanna make this request using AT Commands. I need a example code to send AT Commands to sim7000e using esp32 hardware serial or software serial whichever is the best.

I am using the botlectics library but it has function only for HTTP GET/POST not HTTPS. I am looking for HTTPS request using Sim7000. As there is no function for HTTPS in botletics I thought of sending AT Commands using hardware serial from esp32 to SIM7000 . For example,

`HardwareSerial mySerial(1) ,`

`mySerial.begin(9600,Serial_8N1,13,12)`

And I have connected SIM7000 TX RX with esp32 GPIO 13,12.

then I send AT commands like

`mySerial.print("AT+HTTPINIT\r");`

And I connect FTDI to UOR AND UOT of esp32 which makes Serial.... So no anything done with Serial is with esp32 and writing to mySerial means Sim7000.

I have done this before but with arduino and GSM module through Software Serial and it worked fine.

I think I am missing something in case of ESP32 and Sim7000. In which I need help.

Comment: You mean you have already done a HTTPS POST on the Sim7000 using an Arduino? Sound like that to me. The AT commands are the same, irrelevant, if they are sent by an Arduino or an ESP

Comment: See there's a difference between http post request and https post request right. I used botletics Adaruitfona library for Sim7000 and it has a function for HTTP post request but not the HTTPS post request.  Now I wanna make HTTPS post request with AT commands because there's no function in that library I stated above. I am new to this world and I am facing issues sending AT Commands to SIM7000 from esp32. It was fine when I used software serial for GSM module and arduino but I am not able to do it with esp32 and sim7000. Regarding this I need help.

Comment: Hi @VanshSethi , I read SIM7500/7600/7800 shall work with SSL/HTTPS. Check here: https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM7X00/SIM7500_SIM7600_SIM7800%20Series_SSL_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.00.pdf

Comment: The `AT+HTTPINIT`command suite can't be used for HTTPS, you need to use the `AT+SHCONF` suite. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/baconcheese113/1f0264727fce3fa51a5bb06fa031aed2) for a walkthrough